# How to get the count of all records of a model in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails.

I have an ActiveRecord model called `Post`. I'd like to get count of all the records of the `Post` model. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try google before asking such a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `Post.all.count` in your rails console if you are on Rails 4.

UPDATE:

`Post.count` is better as cristian mentioned

Comment: In Rails 4 this is OK, but in Rails 3 this will fetch all the records from tables posts into memory, create an array of ActiveRecord objects and then run count on that array :D

Comment: @Octopus-Paul : You are right. I guess its same for Rails 4 also.

Comment: Nope, in Rails 4 all return an ActiveRecord::Relation scope object, and not an array. If you run Post.all.count this will have the same effect as Post.count in Rails 4.

Comment: `Post.all.count` is the same as running `Post.count(:all)` which is the same as `Post.count`

Comment: @tagCincy what you are saying is true for Rails 4. In Rails 3 you will get the same result, but if you want to have very bad performance run Post.all.count on a model (in this case Post) with a lot of records.

Answer (score 14):

```
Post.count
```

is what you are looking for.